# Reading multiple files from google bucket & loading into BQ using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

When i try to read files from google bucket and load data in bigquery table, google bucket throws me timeout error. is there a way to read files synchronously and load to bigquery table.

This one works for when files are less, and tried using then as well which also gives same error.

```
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
var fs = require("fs");


const bucketName = 'bucketname';
const gcpProject = "projectname";
const datasetprojectname = "bqprojectname";
const datasetId = "dsname";
const tableId = "tablename";





exports.helloworld = async (req, res) => {


  const bigquery = new BigQuery({ projectId: datasetprojectname });
  const storage = new Storage(gcpProject);
  const loaddatabq = new Storage(gcpProject);
  const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
  const fileoptions = {
    prefix: "singlefile"
  };

  var filecount = 0;
  var errcount = 0;
  var filemoveerrcount = 0;
  const [getfilename] = await bucket.getFiles(fileoptions);
  var filenamespring = "";
  var getjson = null;
          
  getfilename.forEach(async files => {
    try {
      filecount++;
      var filename = files.name;
      
      if (filename != "singlefile/") {  

       var contents =  await files.download(files.name);
          
           await bigquery.dataset(datasetId).table(tableId).insert(JSON.parse(contents).body);       
      }
    }
    catch (err) {
      
    }

  });

};
```

Comment: Is your JSON inline or pretty printed (indented) in the files?

Comment: JSON Inline, which i could modify to pretty printed if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your file are in JSONL (1 JSON document per line, JSON Line), you can use the [load job to achieve this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_json_data_into_a_new_table).

You can filter on the file that you want by [using wildcard character](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data#load-wildcards). It will be more efficient than a for loop.

This solution is also cheaper. You are limited to [1500 loads](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs) per table and per day, but the load is free. In your current code you use the streaming API, and you [pay for it ($0.05 per Gb)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing/#data_ingestion_pricing)

Comment: I have multiple files in bucket, which might hold single or multiple row, there is no direct  ingestion support via nodejs using cloud function support is it?

Comment: All depends on your input format. If you have 1 JSON per line and you have multiple line, i.e. multiple row, it's not a problem, the load API works like that. Same thing for multple file, a wildcard pattern allows to ingest several files in once.